# how to count the number of objects created in c++

Tags: c++

how to count the number of objects created in c++

pls explain with a simple example

Comment: Are you counting only objects created using dynamic allocation or objects with automatic storage (such as the stack)?

Answer (score 33):

Create template class with a static counter.

Each object in your application would then extend this template class.

When constructor is called increment static count (static variable is per class - shared by all objects of that class).

For example see Object Counter using [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
 template <typename T>
    struct counter
    {
        counter()
        {
            objects_created++;
            objects_alive++;
        }

        counter(const counter&)
        {
             objects_created++;
             objects_alive++;
        }   

    protected:
        virtual ~counter()
        {
            --objects_alive;
        }
        static int objects_created;
        static int objects_alive;
    };
    template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_created( 0 );
    template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive( 0 );

    class X : counter<X>
    {
        // ...
    };

    class Y : counter<Y>
    {
        // ...
    };

Usage for completeness:

    int main()
    {
        X x1;

        {
            X x2;
            X x3;
            X x4;
            X x5;
            Y y1;
            Y y2;
        }   // objects gone

        Y y3;

        cout << "created: "
             << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_created
             << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_created  //well done
             << endl;

        cout << "alive: "
             << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_alive
             << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_alive
             << endl;
    }
```

Output:

```
created:  X:5 Y:3
alive:  X:1 Y:1
```

Comment: Hi. Nice approach. I never knew about that. Thanks!

Comment: Some time ago I was doing some static polymorphism and bumped to this example, I really like it, and static polymorphism is cool as well ...

Comment: Nice solution, I have a doubt though.. is it really necessary to make the destructor virtual in the class template when using CRTP? I am just worried about the slight size overhead caused by the v-tables..

Comment: its due to private inheritance since in this case derived class object is not base class one and compiler will not do implicit type conversion.

Comment: is there any other reason for the private inheritance?

Comment: how does this handle.
X x2;
X x3 = x2;

Comment: I think there is no need to make destructor virtual and benefits of private inheritance are : 

1. counter<X> *px = new X; // error no implicit conversion is allowed 

2. delete px; // destructor not accessible

Comment: struct inheritance is public by default, since it's not specified it's public not private, unlike class where the inheritance is public by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, this example only counts the objects created that are derived from the template class.

Comment: you could implement static count in each of your classes by hand, but this simplifies things a bit, you can add custom stuff in classes that need to do more ...

Comment: In normal case, if I try to access static member from constructor we get error message right. So is that is the reason we have to go for template?

Comment: Virtual destructor of counter may increase the size of derived class, because of virtual table. Destructor of counter can be protected, to prevent it from being deleted by pointer of counter.

Comment: Edited the counter, mainly,  to include copy ctor counting. Without it the derived class implicitly could have called the compiler  generated counter version and copies would have been lost.

Comment: @stefanB error: 'objects_created' is a protected member of 'counter<X>', 
error: 'objects_alive' is a protected member of 'counter<X>'

Answer (score 12):

```
template <class T>
class Counter
{
  private:
      static int count;
  public:
    Counter()
    {
       count++;
    }  
    Counter(const Counter &c)
    {
       count++;
    }   
    ~Counter()
    {
       count--;
    }    
    static int GetCount() {

         return count;
    }
}

template<class T> 
int Counter<T>::count = 0; 



class MyClass : private Counter<MyClass>
{
   public:
      using Counter<MyClass>::GetCount;
}
```

This technique is called [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: @stefanB, This is the correct approach. You need to have copy constructor in Counter.

Comment: +1, stefanB's approach does not handle 'X x2; X x3 = x2;'. But you can't initialize count like that, since it's not const.

Answer (score 4):

Number of objects for what? If you want to count the number of objects of a specific class, you can use a static counter. Something like below.. Increment counter on creation and decrement while destruction..

```
class A
{
  public:
    static int counter;
    A()
    {
      counter ++;
    }
    virtual ~A()
    {
      counter --;
    }
};

int A :: counter = 0;
```

Comment: How do you keep track if the object is created using malloc?

Comment: @KranthiKumar It *isn't* 'created by `malloc()`.' It is *allocated* statically, or by `new`, or on the stack; it is *constructed* by one of its constructors; and it is destroyed by its destructor.

Answer (score 4):

You have to overload the new and delete operators
to count memory allocations.

```
void * operator new (size_t size)
{
    void * p = malloc (size);
    num_allocations++;
    return p;
}

void operator delete (void * p)
{
    num_deletions++;
    free (p);
}
```

Comment: I think new [] and delete [] also have to be overloaded if you want to track objects on heap .

Comment: Yes you are correct Mac. I was just trying to get him started. You need to overload every variation of new that you are using.

Comment: doesnt that break the code? delete should call destructor first;

Comment: I think there is not need to overload the `new` /  `delete` operators because AFAIK the `new` operator invokes the object's constructor and the corresponding call to delete invokes the object's destructor.

Comment: @DevDevDev if you use the default constructor / destructor of a class, the "new / delete operators" are not being executed

Answer (score 0):

You could create a counter variable into the public: of your class (assuming here you're talking about counting objects from a class you created)

```
class Widget {
public:
    Widget() { ++count; }
    Widget(const Widget&) { ++count; }
    ~Widget() { --count; }

    static size_t howMany()
    { return count; }

private:
    static size_t count;
};
// obligatory definition of count. This
// goes in an implementation file
size_t Widget::count = 0;
```

Taken from [ddj.com](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403484)

Comment: you should read the whole article from scott meyers to see that this solutions is not the best. At the end of the article he describes the template approach mentioned in the other posts.

Answer (score 0):

update on code as opposed to "stefanB" solution, some variables are in protected access mode and will not be accessible.

```
template <typename T>
    struct counter
    {
        counter()
        {
            std::cout << "object created"<< endl;
            this->objects_created++;
            this->objects_alive++;
        }

        counter(const counter& test)
        {
            std::cout << "object created:" << test << endl;
             this->objects_created++;
             this->objects_alive++;
        }

        static int getObjectsAlive(){
            return objects_alive;
        }

        static int getObjectsCreated(){
            return objects_created;
        }


    protected:
        virtual ~counter()
        {
            std::cout << "object destroyed"<< endl;
            --objects_alive;
        }
        static int objects_created;
        static int objects_alive;
    };
    template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_created( 0 );
    template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive( 0 );

    class X : counter<X>
    {
        // ...
    };

    class Y : counter<Y>
    {
        // ...
    };
    
    Usage for completeness:
    
        int main()
        {
            X x1;
        
            {
                X x2;
                X x3;
                X x4;
                X x5;
                Y y1;
                Y y2;
            }   // objects gone
        
            Y y3;
         
    cout << "created: "
         << " X:" << counter<X>::getObjectsCreated()
         << " Y:" << counter<Y>::getObjectsCreated()  //well done
         << endl;

    cout << "alive: "
         << " X:" << counter<X>::getObjectsAlive()
         << " Y:" << counter<Y>::getObjectsAlive()
         << endl;
        }
```