# Count object created on Heap and stack

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class and I can create its object on stack and heap. How should I count the number of objects created on Heap and stack in C++.
Can we do it by using static member variable and overloading new operator.

Comment: If you're compiler is using a stack. consider that when you pass parameters, the parameters are placed on the stack, along with the return address.  Variables in a block statement may be pushed onto the stack, then when execution leaves the block, the variables are removed from the stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting of objects created in stack and heap for many classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004963/counting-of-objects-created-in-stack-and-heap-for-many-classes)

Comment: Are you asking to count the maximum number of objects pushed onto the stack at one point?  Remember, the number of variables may also be affected by the depth of function calls and recursion.

Comment: When you say "stack", what do you mean exactly? Do you mean the underlying stack mechanism inside your C++ implementation? Which includes function arguments and all sorts of stuff? Or do you mean C++ objects with automatic storage duration declared in your function? Let's use proper, precise terminology for clear answers!

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: You can overload new/malloc and family to do this.  It is a common debug tool in embedded land.