# Initialisation of my static data member to 0 in CPP file before two constructors

Tags: c++, class, static, member

Can I do this? 
it tells me unresolved external symbol WTH!

I really need to initialise the value of `GameObjectCount` to `Zero`.

Also, when I use the Default constructor to build an object, I cant access any of its members!

WHY?

**main.cpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "MapTile.h" 
#include "GameOb.h"

MapTile backGRIND("Name");
GameOb test();

int main(int, char**){   ////this main is for SDL2////

    std::cout << backGRIND.texturePath << std::endl;
    std::cout << backGRIND.GameObjectCount << backGRIND.x << backGRIND.ObjectID << std::endl;
```

**GameOb.cpp**

```
#include "GameOb.h"


int GameOb::GameObjectCount = 0;

GameOb::GameOb()
{
    GameOb::GameObjectCount++; 

    GameOb::x = 0;
    GameOb::y = 0;
    GameOb::ObjectID = GameObjectCount; 

    GameOb::texturePath = std::string("Ressources/GameObjects/"); 

    std::cout << "Object has been created with Object ID : " << GameOb::ObjectID << std::endl;
}

GameOb::GameOb(int x, int y)
{
    GameOb::GameObjectCount++;

    GameOb::x = x;
    GameOb::y = y;
    GameOb::ObjectID = GameObjectCount;     

    GameOb::texturePath = std::string("Ressources/GameObjects/");

    std::cout << "Object has been created with Object ID : " << GameOb::ObjectID << std::endl;
}
```

**GameOb.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>  

class GameOb
{
public:

    GameOb();
    GameOb(int, int);

    ~GameOb();

    int x;
    int y;
    int ObjectID;

    std::string texturePath;

    void update(int, int, int);

    static int GameObjectCount;
};
```

**MapTile.cpp**

```
#include "MapTile.h"



MapTile::MapTile(std::string name)
{       
    GameOb::texturePath += std::string("MapTile/");
}


MapTile::~MapTile()
{
}
```

**MapTile.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "GameOb.h"       

class MapTile :
    public GameOb     
{
public:
    MapTile(std::string);



    ~MapTile();    

};
```

OK SO ITS DONE

why cant I access the test instances members?? when i write test.(nothing shows)?? help ... im really new at this.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Err, what's in "GameOb.h"?

Comment: The answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926605/how-to-count-the-number-of-objects-created-in-c might solve your problem of getting a count of how many objects have been created.  There are a few possible solutions.  But  EJP has probably answered your question.

Comment: Sorry for not posting .h :S was late :(

Comment: I am completely making things overcomplicated for nothing!!! GameOb needs no x.y(just need 1 constructor not two)!!!    Sorry for wasting ur guys time ...

Comment: I've been doing this for about a month now, if anyone wants to look over this code for fun, tell me what I do wrong, if I have a bad style or anything.. Thank you in adv

Comment: Whew! 3 years such improvement :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless `GameOb.h` contains at a minimum the following:

```
class GameOb
{
    static int GameCount;
    static int ObjectID;
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static std::string texturePath;

    GameOb();

    GameOb(int x, int y);
}
```

your code cannot possibly compile.

I don't consider it likely or desirable that `x` and `y` and `ObjectID` and `texturePath` are really meant to be static, but that's the implication of the code you posted. So you also need to look up the correct way to initialize data members in a constructor, and the correct way to refer to non-static members.