# Counting number of objects of different classes

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I would like to count the number of objects that my program creates over its lifetime. Based on the solution provided here:

[how to count the number of objects created in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926605/how-to-count-the-number-of-objects-created-in-c)

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace::std;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
struct counter
{
    counter()
    {
        objects_created++;
        objects_alive++;
    }

    virtual ~counter()
    {
        --objects_alive;
    }
    static int objects_created;
    static int objects_alive;
};
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_created(0);
template <typename T> int counter<T>::objects_alive(0);

class X : counter<X>
{
    int a;
};

class Y : counter<Y>
{
    int b;
};

void fooX(class X x) {
    cout << "passing object" << endl;
}

void fooY(class Y& y) {
    cout << "passing reference" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "created: " << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_created << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_created << endl;
    cout << "alive: " << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_alive << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_alive << endl;
    X x;
    Y y;
    cout << "created: " << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_created << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_created << endl;
    cout << "alive: " << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_alive << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_alive << endl;
    fooX(x);
    fooY(y);
    cout << "created: " << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_created << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_created << endl;
    cout << "alive: " << " X:" << counter<X>::objects_alive << " Y:" << counter<Y>::objects_alive << endl;
    int ui;
    cin >> ui;
}
```

I expected that since `x` is passed by value, a copy of it is made inside `fooX` making the total number of objects of `class X` to be 2 while since `y` is passed by reference, the total number of objects of `class Y` to be 1.

Yet, the output of the code is as follows:

```
created:  X:0 Y:0
alive:  X:0 Y:0
created:  X:1 Y:1
alive:  X:1 Y:1
passing object
passing reference
created:  X:1 Y:1
alive:  X:0 Y:1
```

Why does not the number of `X`s created be 2?

Comment: You forgot the copy constructor in the base class: `counter(T const &)`

Comment: @RichardCritten I was under the mistaken understanding then that if the user does not provide one, the compiler automatically does. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: The compiler does provide one, but it may not do what you want.

Comment: The default copy constructor is really, really dumb. It does the absolute minimum to copy the data members (leading to much fun with pointers and other resources that require special handling. For more see [What Is the Rule Of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)) and nothing more. It does not increment the counters, and it does not pass go and collect $200.

Comment: Also conciser what happens to the counters in the LHS object of `operator=` And don't forget Copy elision: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @RichardCritten: I think assignment operator need not increment the counter since `X x1; X x2;...x1 = x2;` assignment already needs pre-existing objects where the counter would have been already incremented during object's initial creation. I have to think about elision but my code does not have such structures as of now.

Comment: The default assignment operator is going overwrite the LHS counters with the values from the RHS, this is not what you want.  So you need to implement the operator to not do this.

Comment: hmm...but if x1 and x2 belong to the same class X, the counters being static  are at the class level, so even if they are overridden, I think it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A copy constructor is automatically added to your `counter` class, and that automatically created copy constructor doesn't increment your static variables.

Write a copy constructor which does that:

```
counter(counter const&)
{
    objects_created++;
    objects_alive++;
}
```

---

Note that your destructor should probably not be `virtual`, unless you intend to delete dynamically created instances of derived classes via pointers or references to `counter`. As it stands, it's just premature pessimisation because it needlessly increases the size of your objects.

Comment: I added `counter(T const & t) {objects_created++;objects_alive++;}` to the code above and reran, it still gives me the same result as I indicated in the OP. That is, the number of objects created of X is still shown to be 1 and not 2.

Comment: @Tryer: That's because `counter(T const & t)` isn't a copy constructor. It's just a normal constructor taking a `T`, like `counter(int number)` or `counter(std::string const& text)`.

Comment: Yes. I changed that to the code you have in your answer and it works. Thank you!